# URL alias for language frontpage

Tags: drupal, translation, drupal-7

I have set Drupal to determine the language from the URL (path prefix), thus `/` is english and `/da` is Danish.
This works fine for all pages except `/da`

The frontpage for Danish is `/node/14` but it doesnt show when I go to `/da`

Also content marked *Language neutral* is not showing for any language.

Any ideas?

p.s. I'm using Drupal 7.0 Alpha 2

Comment: Don't use Drupal 7. It has many bugs and still in Alpha. Drupal 6 is stable version.

Answer (score 1):

As I know in **D6**, you can insert a record into `{url_alias}` table and everything will be ok then.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't connect the path with the node. Maybe a bug in D7

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug. Do you have pathauto module enabled? http://drupal.org/project/pathauto

Answer (score 0):

I don't think core has the ability to set an individual front page for each language. You'd have to use a module like http://drupal.org/project/i18n, which has yet to have any work completed with porting to Drupal 7.

Comment: I agree; without using any third-party modules, in Drupal the front page is only one, which is the one set in the settings.

Comment: I don't use Drupal any more thus I don't know which answer to accept, sorry.